# Good informational material on BTC trading? Market vs limit?

Tags: exchanges

I just signed up on Gemini, and I have to admit that I have no idea what I'm doing. Is there any place I can study up on how this works?

Comment: I would start [here](http://www.investopedia.com/university/forexmarket/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investopedia.org is good, in general.

To answer the other part of your question (Market vs. Limit):

A market order is an order that will execute at whatever the current price is (no matter what - so be careful).  A limit order is an order that will execute only at the price you specify (or better, so it's much safer).